# Has anyone made explorercanvas work with GWT?

Tags: gwt, canvas, excanvas

Has anyone made explorercanvas work with GWT?  Can you share the exact code?

I see a lot of references to explorercanvas with GWT.  For example:  http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/wiki/Instructions  But these are always filled with caveats and complaints.  I haven't seen any complete solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I have done so for a project. I created a module which you can inherit and use in your gwt application and use the GWT Canvas class to write your code. You can see the details in my blog.

http://ummeessa.blogspot.com/2011/09/gwtcanvas-on-ie7-and-8.html

Hope the blog will help you creating your own module.

I have used my module in a project to create charts using canvas. It works fine in IE7/8 and I am sure there should be no issues. Everything which is supported by excanvas works in my module.

Comment: Thanks.  This looks promising.

One question.  Where you wrote value="ie6", did you mean "ie7"?